# Is it possible to start the Axon server embedded in my spring-boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

According to the Axon documentation, the Axon server could be run from the command line or deployed in a docker container. I was wondering if it would be possible/recommended to start it directly from my spring-boot application, by manually instantiating the server class.

Could you guys please share your experience with it?

Obs: For security reasons, I am not allowed to start the Axon server in our production server unless it were packed together with our application.

Comment: AFAIK Axon has its own Spring Boot starter, care to elaborate the issue you're facing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as far as I understand, what we have for Spring boot is the Axon auto-configuration, allowing us to inject the dependencies needed for both publishing and/or subscribing the messages using the Axon framework. The Axon server itself stills needs to be started, separately, outside the spring boot application.

Comment: It has been a while since I last used it, so i don't know if this has changed, but at the time, you really wanted Axon server to be up and running *before* starting your application.

Comment: Yes. I will believe you are right @Mzzl. As well, trying to hack it, at the moment,  does not seem a good idea to me. The Axon server, at least on tests I've done on my local, demanded access to other system resources, like writing to the filesystem, which would probably make this solution unstable.

Comment: Are you running your entire application and Axon Server in the same VM or container? You can run it without axon server and just use a regular database.

Comment: @Mzzl could you share some reference documentation I could follow in order to do it? In every example I've found, it is always implicit the Axon should already be running, otherwise, it does not work.

Comment: You can use the JpaEventStorageEngine, which is the default as long as you have JPA on the classpath and not something else explicitly configured, but you're right they prefer Axon Server in current examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, Axon Server cannot run in an 'embedded' form like you're asking, @Davi.
Thus, for Axon Server version 4.1.x, this isn't an option.

It is obviously not ruled out that this might chance in the future, as it is **definitely** not a weird thing to ask.
Prioritization on this feature has not taken place yet, but requests of interest like you've done right now might chance that.
I'd suggest following the AxonIQ mail notifications on this part, as once this will be introduced I am pretty certain it'll be shared through those channels.

Additionaly, like @Mzzl is sharing, Axon Server is not a hard requirement to running an Axon Framework application. It's the preferred format as it provides a dedicated solution for routing commands, events and queries, as well as a purpose build Event Store which in the long run is far more suitable to store events then a regular RDBMS approach.

However, if this is not the way to go within your application, or differently put, you want to configure the routing and storage of those messages yourself, than it is perfectly fine to exclude the connection to server by excluding the `axon-server-connector` dependency.

Comment: Hi Steve, I really appreciate your answer. Thank you very much for your time to come here and explain it and congrats for the great job with the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your support on this @Davi! Feel free to drop new questions here on StackOverflow regarding Axon whenever something's unclear - we monitor any new `axon` tagged questions to simplify the usage of it as good as possible.